# Inconsistent recycling in R?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, recycle

In R code example 1:

```
mat <- matrix(1, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
avec <- c(2, 3)
mat[avec, avec] <- 0
```

mat is:

```
1    1    1    1
1    0    0    1
1    0    0    1
1    1    1    1
```

But in example 2:

```
res <- avec + avec
```

res is (4, 6)

In other words, in example 1, recycling avec generates the pairs (2, 2),
(2, 3), (3, 2), and (3, 3), while in example 2, the pairs are (2, 2) and
(3, 3).  Isn't the recycling inconsistent in these two examples?

Comment: Zheyuan, thanks very much for your careful exposition, and for the
excellent reference.  Sorry for the sloppy use of "recycling".  I lack R
vocabulary.  I was trying to develop an intuition for how R might default in terms of handling
expressions with multiple vectors in them, when there is nothing obvious
in the expression to indicate how.  But maybe there is no such default.

Comment: For example, paste(c("X","Y"), 1:10, sep="") produces X1, Y2, X3, etc.
One might expect on those grounds that [avec, avec] in example 1 would
produce (2,2) and (3,3), but it doesn't.